# Entire $f$ and $g$ satisfying $f^n+g^n=1$ for $n>3$ must be constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

Studying for a qualifying exam and came across [Don Marshall's notes](http://www.math.washington.edu/~marshall/math_534/Notes1.pdf). This one has stumped me for some time. This question is related to [another MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167329/f-g-entire-functions-with-f2-g2-equiv-1-implies-exists-h-entire-wit):

$\begin{align*}\text{If $f$ and $g$ are entire and } [f(z)]^n+[g(z)]^n=1\text{ for $n>3$ then $f,g$ are constant}.
\end{align*}$

The most I could deduce is that if $f$ were not constant then $[f(z)]^n$ is necessarily surjective as missing one value for $[f(z)]^n$ would force $n$ missed values for $f$. That's about as far as I could get.

Comment: You were very close ;)

Comment: Absolutely a duplicate. Despite my search I couldn't find the page you linked to before I posted.

Comment: No problem, searching isn't easy. I knew something more to look for, and I knew there was the duplicate. So I was able to find it.